# Phoenix input opts list

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

Is there a definitive list of the opts taken in by text_input, number_input, etc. 
I am trying to enforce a specific numerical length on an input box but do not want the up down arrows that come with using the number_input tag

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: There's no such list. You can put custom attributes.

Longer answer: Each `X_input` function have such chain of execution

```
# Phoenix.HTML.Form

X_input
|> generic_input
|> tag # imported from Phoenix.HTML.Tag

#Phoenix.HTML.Tag

def tag(name, attrs) when is_list(attrs) do
  {:safe, [?<, to_string(name), build_attrs(name, attrs), ?>]}
end
```

so it comes to `build_attrs`, which basically filter only keys, which have values as lists and accept everything else.

https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_html/blob/master/lib/phoenix_html/tag.ex#L120